# .NET Custom Control with a Wizard

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, custom-controls, asp.net-customcontrol

I'm developing a .NET Control and there's a need to add a Wizard to Configure its options. example: SQL Configuration Wizard of SQL Control in Visual Studio a.k.a. Data Source Configuration Wizard. How can I make one like that? Where to start?

**Edit:** The solution should be entirely CODE based which I can manipulate as I wish.

Answer (score 0):

You can try DevExpress's XtraWizard. Take a look [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Wizard/) . I use it and I recommend it.

Comment: I can't use any third party apps. And besides that, XtraWizard creates/provides Wizard Controls, not Wizards in Control Configuration. @eburgos

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding it. I see you're developing a control and you want to make it configurable via a wizard, like for example configuring a database connection control.